# Изменить текст индексной страницы Nginx Debian 11

Tags: nginx, debian

Как найти в домашней директории индексный файл по умолчанию - index.html ?
И изменить текст индексной страницы ?
Nginx Debian 11

Answer (score 1):

Имя индексного файла указывается в директиве [index](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index).

А путь к корневой папке в директиве [root](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).

Чтобы посмотреть весь конфиг Nginx можно дать в терминале команду `nginx -T`

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите.

Comment: Мне надо удалить /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html и создать вместо него  index.html. Как это сделать?

Comment: при помощи текстового редактора. Я предпочитаю использовать vim